# PingFederate WS-Fed error Crypto algorithm sha512 not supported in this context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, saml-2.0, pingfederate

I am trying to authenticate with a PingFederate Idp. I am using asp.net mvc4 which provides wsfed via the Identity and access tool. It appears I am getting the saml assertion back fine. The Idp does require that the certificate is present and confirmed on the SP. I have the certificate from the Idp and installed it in trusted roots. I am using this line in web.config to have it look in trusted roots.

```
<certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" / >
```

This is the exact error I am getting from my asp.net:

Crypto algorithm 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512' not supported in this context.

If it is finding the correct cert and just can't do sha512, what are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SHA512 isn't supported out of the box for .NET applications (don't ask me why). It can be enabled on a per application basis. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21435041/280222.

This should work if pingfederate picks up the global algorithm list, but I've not worked with pingfederate myself so I'm not sure of the solution.